# perl SSH to router change default prompt

Tags: perl, ssh

I am supporse to login to router through SSH using module (Net::SSH::Expect).

Any idea how to change default prompt because when I try to run below code (portion of code)
I am getting no output.

```
my $session = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
        host => 'bsin810',
        user => "$user",
        password=> "$pass",
        timeout => 10,
        raw_pty => 1
    );


$session->run_ssh();


$session->exec("term len 0");
@op=$session->exec("sh run int lo99");
@op1=$session->exec("sh isis neighbor");
```

Here is way I login to router through server.

%ssh xxxx@bsin810

Password:

Welcome

Now when I changed code for interactive commands its working fine. Below code works fine.

```
my $session = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
        host => "$node",
        user => "$user",
        timeout => 10,
        raw_pty => 1
    );


$session->run_ssh();


$session->waitfor('password: ');
$session->send("$pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after `run_ssh`

```
#Test if you received the remote prompt:
($ssh->read_all(2) =~ />\s*\z/) or die "where's the remote prompt?"
```

From [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect)

> If you won't run on the server interactive commands that prompt for
>   input, like 'passwd', you could prevent the ssh server from
>   attributing a ptty for the ssh login process. This is done by enabling
>   the 'no_terminal' constructor attribute. What that does is passing the
>   '-T' option to the ssh client process when it is created. From the BSD
>   ssh client manual: -T Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
>
> This will create the cleaner connection possible. You won't have a
>   ptty on the server, and, weirdly, you won't receive a remote prompt.
>   Try yourself 'ssh -T my.ssh.server' to see how it works. Notice that
>   some system commands that rely on a terminal won't work, say, 'who am
>   i', 'stty', etc.
>
> Also, interactive commands like 'passwd' or 'mail' won't be able to
>   print their prompts.
>
> But other system commands will run better: 'ls -l' will be printed
>   without terminal control characters. 'ps -ef' will have the command
>   lines printed fully, since there is no 'columns' terminal limitation.
>
> Moral of the story: pseudo terminals do many character translations
>   that can bring some unexpected results in some situations. Avoid them
>   if you can.